# Can a swift package provide support for other packages, without having them as dependencies?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm making a package, and I want to provide some extensions for another package if it is included in the module that consumes my package. I'm thinking, something like:

```
#if canImport(PromiseKit)
import PromiseKit
// Perhaps some internal extension on a PromiseKit class, as a helper for below
// Some public extension on my class. This code will use PromiseKit.
#endif
```

The idea is that if a consuming module installs my package, and if they happen to have PromiseKit as well, then my package provides some support for PromiseKit. Besides that, my package does not need PromiseKit as a dependancy at all.

Initially, I need to mark PromiseKit as a dependancy in my Package.swift, so Xcode can install it, so I can get autocomplete help when writing the extensions. But if I leave it at that, installing my package will install PromiseKit anyway because it marks it as a dependancy, making the `canImport` redundant.

So after writing the code inside `canImport`, should I just remove the dependancy from Package.swift?

But then, after some time, if PromiseKit's API changes, a consuming module that installs my package will no longer be able to compile, right?

Is there a good way to do this? If a package doesn't have any dependencies, but provides some support for packages A, B, C, D, E, F, ideally, if someone installed my package, I don't want it to also install all those packages. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is what I'm trying to do bad practice?

---

**Updated:**

I discovered something very peculiar. My strategy was simple:

1. Declare a dependancy
2. Write support code for it
3. Remove the dependancy
4. Brace it in a `#if canImport(...)`

Turns out this won't work. I know this because I installed my package in a new project, and also installed PromiseKit, yet my support code was inaccessible, despite numerous cleans, rebuilds, and Xcode restarts.

It's lead me to believe that the code `#if canImport(...)` is not run in a context that knows about the environment of the new project. It's run in some other context. Otherwise, it would find that PromiseKit is installed, and that code would run, and its API would be available.

Note that if I declare the PromiseKit dependancy in my package, and update the new project's packages, Xcode installs PromiseKit automatically, and my support code becomes accessible. But then the `#if canImport(...)` is essentially redundant, and my package ends up bringing all these packages along with it, which I don't want to do.

The question could be reduced to: "Can a package know if a module is available in the consuming project?"

Comment: I'm not an expert but it sounds like what you're already doing should be great. If PromiseKit is present the user gets the benefits of your support and if it isn't no harm done.

Comment: @matt Thanks Mr. Neuburg :) I'm a big fan of your books by the way  I've read them multiple times over  They have been beloved companions. Sorry for fanboying lol

Comment: Well I'm happy about that but be warned, I know very little about packages! But reading your plan, thinking about it from the point of view of a user of your package, your `#canImport` idea sounds like just what I'd want.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to get it to work.

1. Declare a dependancy
2. Write support code for it
3. Brace it in a `#if canImport(...)`
4. Remove the dependancy

Now the fickle part. In the consuming package, as soon I install my package, my support code **is** accessible. But once I run clean then it's game over; it will no longer compile after running clean. In which case I found out that I needed to remove my package, clean, build, install it again, build. Then it will compile successfully; the compiler is aware of the support code API. I can run it as well, and the support code works.